# Overriding generic getters with proper return type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have come across an issue with Java generics when attempting to make a small system.

```
public void bar(){
    final Shape shape = new Shape();
    final Painter<Shape> shapePainter = shape.getPainter();

    final Circle circle = new Circle();
    final Painter<Circle> circlePainter = circle.getPainter();
}

class Shape {

    public Painter<? extends Shape> getPainter(){
        return new Painter<>(this);
    }

}

class Circle extends Shape {

    @Override
    public Painter<Circle> getPainter(){
        return new CirclePainter(this);
    }

}

class Painter<E extends Shape> {

    public Painter(final E element){
        // ...
    }

    public void paint(final E shape){
        // ...
    }
    
}

class CirclePainter extends Painter<Circle> {

    public CirclePainter(final Circle element){
        super(element);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(final Circle shape){
        // ...
    }
}
```

This fails on compilation with an error on line 3 (`final Painter<Shape> shapePainter = shape.getPainter();`) saying:

> Incompatible types:
>
> Required: Bar.Painter < org.example.Bar.Shape>
>
> Found: Bar.Painter < capture< ? extends org.example.Bar.Shape>>

This can then be fixed by changing the faulty line to:

```
final Painter<?> shapePainter = shape.getPainter();
```

However, subsequent calls like:

```
shapePainter.paint(shape);
```

Will throw another exception:

> paint (capture< ? extends org.example.Bar.Shape>) in Painter cannot be applied
>
> to    (org.example.Bar.Shape)

---

I feel like I am missing some simple part of Java generics that could help resolve this issue. I have tried fiddling around with the return type of `Shape#getPainter`, but this usually leaves compiler errors in `Circle#getPainter` or in `bar` that don't seem to have any possible solution.

If this is not possible with generics, what other solutions are available?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your entire class generic, using the CRTP:

```
class Shape<T extends Shape<T> {

    public Painter<T> getPainter(){
        return new Painter<>(this);
    }

}
class Painter<E extends Shape<E>> { ... }
```

Comment: This resolved neither issue and now there is an error of incompatible types with the `this` parameter on line 12 (`return new Painter<>(this);`).

Comment: @Obicere: AFAIK, you can only solve that by either making it return `Painter<Shape<T>>`, or using a cast.  The problem is that you could write `class Triangle extends Shape<Square>`; the compiler cannot prove that `this` is `T`.